# Guzzle 6: Two-legged OAuth1 Authorisation

Tags: php, oauth, guzzle, guzzle6

I am using Guzzle 6 and [OAuth Subscriber](https://github.com/guzzle/oauth-subscriber) for machine-to-machine communcation, interfacing with an API with base uri https://foo.bar ofwhich the vendor provides following parameter instructiond:

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Request Token URL: https://foo.bar/oauth/request
- Authorize URL: https://foo.bar/oauth/authorize
- Access Token URL: https://foo.bar/oauth/access

Following [The OAuth Bible](https://github.com/Mashape/mashape-oauth/blob/master/FLOWS.md#oauth-10a-three-legged), would imply that two-legged OAuth is required, as I wish to bypass the manual authorisation redirection, though am unsure how to how/where to-set the request-token URL and Access Token URL at client level.

I have setup a simple client, using only consumer-key and secret, but this allows only partial API access

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$middleware = new Oauth1([
        'consumer_key' => $params['consumerKey'],
        'consumer_secret' => $params['consumerSecret'],
        'token_secret' => false,
    ]);

$stack->push($middleware);
$client=new Client([
        'base_uri' => $params['baseUri'],
        'handler' => $stack,
        'auth' => 'oauth'
]);

//Leg #1: Obtain application request token  
$requestTokenResponse = $client->post('/oauth/request')->getBody()->getContents();
/* requestTokenResponse now contains in a single string variable with value: 
 *'oauth_token=4plbxbL9Um9J6IN7XLDy5DYDwJlrISQ5QMqi43JaXaQ&
 * oauth_callback_confirmed=true&
 * oauth_token_secret=JqCC51ja3Q2yklV2xyphUromHGhIwWjgcx%40hXvO3JosbkYWKVr'
*/
$requestTokenParams = [];
foreach (explode('&',$requestTokenResponse) as $queryString) {
        $query = explode('=', $queryString);
        $requestTokenParams[$query[0]] = $query[1];
}
//Leg #2 Starts Here

//Dynamically add middleware params (setting token and token_secret?) 

//Obtain access token after middleware update
    $accessTokenResponse = $client->post('/oauth/access')->getBody()->getContents();
```

I'm not sure how to advance now:

It would seem that the next post requires setting up the token and token_secret, requiring me to modify the middleware parameters before the next call, which doesn't seem to work and/or pushing to the handler-stack manually..

Please help,
Thanks in advance